# How to get HTML node object and not the HTML itself with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, object, nodes

When I do

`var el = document.querySelector('.some-class');`

I get the plain HTML.

How then do I get access to the Javascript node element?

I can see it when I do `dir(el)` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the dom itself. You can manipulate the element with only this. Why it is showing the HTML, it is just a common way that the console shows you. If you want to add a class for example, you can do.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.some-class');
el.classList.add('test')
```

This will work as it should. If you want to HTML of the element, you could also do:

```
el.outerHTML
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) returns an [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) object, which implements the `Element` interface which inherits from the [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface.